# Buildfire: Is there anyway to add user tags from within a plugin?

Tags: buildfire

Just like how you can add tags within the control panel to label specific users, is there anyway to add the same type of tags from within the buildfire SDK?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, but I am not getting what exactly are you trying to ask in this Question?

Answer (score 1):

No. This is locked down due to security reasons.

However, you can set up behavioral Tagging via the control panel that may achieve what you need.

Example: You want to unlock lesson plan Level-2 only after the user completes Level-1. You can set up a "Congratulations/Text" plugin that Tags any users that lands on it with "Level2". You cannot navigate to this plugin anywhere on the app except after you have finished the last step in the lesson plan. Once this tag has been assigned you can then unlock the Level-2 lesson plan.

I hope this helps.